# Why do we want to define a $k$-scheme to be birational if the rational map (and its inverse) to $\Bbb A_k^n$ is over $k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, terminology, definition

Two varieties $X,Y$ are said to be birational if there exist rational maps in each direction such that either composition is the identity on a open dense subset. Note that here the morphisms aren't assumed to be over any base scheme.

However, to say that an integral finite type $k$-scheme is rational (i.e. birational to $\Bbb A_k^n$), one imposes that the rational map (and its inverse) to $\Bbb A_k^n$ be over $k$. Why?

An integral finite type $k$-scheme, by definition, can be covered by finitely many $U_i =\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,...,x_{n_i}]/I_i$, but, if I understood everything correctly so far, there is no restriction on how $k$ maps into $k[x_1,...,x_{n_i}]/I_i.$ I suppose that it doesn't even have to land in $k$ as shows the example $\phi:\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)\rightarrow\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x_1]/(x_1^2-2)$ by $1\mapsto 1, \sqrt2\mapsto x_1$.

**EDIT:** I realize now that what I said in the last paragraph is not entirely correct. For a finite type $k$-scheme, one can actually find affine opens $\operatorname{Spec} B_i$ such that $B_i$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. This means that $k$ maps into $B_i=k[x_1,...,x_{n_i}]/I$ in the obvious (standard) way. This doesn't mean, however, that you cannot find other $A_j$, also of the form $k[x_1,...,x_{n_j}]/J$ into which the map induced by $\operatorname{Spec}k\rightarrow X$ maps $k$ into $A_j$ in a non-standard way (as in my example above).

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, since I'm still sometimes confused about terminology, could I ask you to verify if the amendment I did in my last **EDIT** (the last paragraph) is correct? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Which source are you reading? When dealing with varieties over a field $k$, of course one only considers morphisms over $k$. This applies - in particular - to birational maps. They are (partially defined) $k$-morphisms.

When you consider morphisms not over $k$, you actually leave the category of varieties and work in the larger category of schemes. So we have a(nother) secret application of a forgetful functor.

Comment: Well, this isn't much of an answer (but it is okay, since it's a soft question). What I am after is whether there is any geometric reason to consider only such maps. One particular instance in which I see why one wants to consider only morphisms over $k$ between $k$-schemes is when what one has in mind are the $k$-valued points of a $k$-scheme $X$. These $k$-valued points should be only the morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} k \rightarrow X$ which over $\operatorname{Spec} k$ so that we can actually see them as points with coordinates in $k$.

Comment: Nota bene, I actually can't prove that $k$-valued points would not correspond to points with coordinates in $k$ if they were not restricted to be morphisms over $k$. And my source (Ravi Vakil) did not spell out in the definition of a $k$-valued point of a $k$-scheme $X$ that the morphism is meant to be over $k$. He even said that my interpretation is valid for "$A$-valued points of an affine scheme (finite type over $\Bbb Z$". I understood the addition of "finite type over $\Bbb Z$" to mean that this interpretation works here because then the map is trivially over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Anyways, if you do restrict $k$-valued points of a $k$-scheme to mean morphisms necessarily over $k$, then the interpretation of these morphisms as the actual points with coordinates in $k$ does work.